# VueJs 2 hide and show DIVs in one html page

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I'm building an application but not a SPA. There are some `div`'s in my page that I want to show and hide step by step. Here is my code:

```
 <div v-if="sectionIs('section1')" class="container">
 </div>

  <div v-if="sectionIs('section2')" class="container">
 </div>

 <div v-if="sectionIs('section3')" class="container">
 </div>
```

And in my js file :

```
var vm = new Vue({
  el: '#standard_registeration',

  data: {
    section : 'section1',
  },

  computed: {
    sectionIs: function (sectionName) {
      return this.section === sectionName
    }
  }
});
```

I want to know if I'm doing this right, or if there is a better (shorter, cleaner) approach?

What if I want to add animation to later?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Computed properties do not take arguments. Instead, just test in the template.

```
<div v-if="section === 'section1'" class="container"></div>
<div v-if="section === 'section2'" class="container"></div>
<div v-if="section === 'section3'" class="container"></div>
```

If you want to add animation later, wrap all of the above in a `transition`.

```js
var vm = new Vue({
  el: '#standard_registeration',
  data: {
    section: 'section1',
  },
  mounted(){
    setInterval(() => {
      let random = Math.floor(Math.random() * (2 - 0 + 1)) + 0;
      this.section = ['section1', 'section2', 'section3'][random]
    }, 2000)
  }
});
```

```css
.fade-enter-active, .fade-leave-active {
  transition: opacity .5s
}
.fade-enter, .fade-leave-to /* .fade-leave-active below version 2.1.8 */ {
  opacity: 0
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.2.6/dist/vue.js"></script>

<div id="standard_registeration">
    <div v-if="section === 'section1'" class="container">
      <h1>Section One</h1>
    </div>
    <div v-if="section === 'section2'" class="container">
      <h1>Section Two</h1>
    </div>
    <div v-if="section === 'section3'" class="container">
      <h1>Section Three<h1>
    </div>
</div>
```